# Display data from variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Let me open by quickly mentioning I'm brand new to this coding stuff, so I'm sorry if I need things in with a teaspoon.

I'm trying to use a finished java script file to display some data on my page using html.

This is the javascript:

```
var Dictionary = function(words) {

this.search = function(query) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(query, "i"); // i - ignore case
    return $.grep(words, function(w) {
        return pattern.test(w);
    });
};


this.size = function() {
    return words.length;
}


this.all = function() {
    return words;
}

}
```

My only task right now is to display this "words" variable that it mentions, but I can't figure out how to display it using html, even though it looks like most of the work is done in the javascript.

I've tried a few desperate things, like "return.dictionary", but that didn't do anything. I hope you can help me out.

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--
  SAMABARBEIDSPARTNERE:

-->

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>IS-104 Søkeside (LAB1)</title>

<!-- Aktuelle Javascript biblioteker laste inn her -->
<!-- Last inn en versjon av jquery her -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lab1-words-small.json"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="lab1-dictionary.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[

// Here er en "hack" for å kunne tvinge denne delen av JavaScript koden å kjøre
// etter at resten av siden er ferdig lastet i din nettleser.
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dict = new Dictionary(words);
    // Din kode kan skrives her

});

// ]]>
</script>


-->
<style type="text/css">

/* Eventuelt din CSS her. Dette er kun et eksempel. */
    html {
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
    }
    h1{
        font-family: Verdana, Serif;
        text-align: center;
    }

    nav ul{height:200px; width:18%; background-color: #FFFFFF; margin: auto; position: relative; right:50px}
    nav ul{overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;}

    form{
        width:500px;
        margin:50px auto;
        position: relative;
        left: 95px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body style="align:center">
<!-- Din HTML skrives her -->
    <h1>
        Dette er en liste og søkeside for en ordbok.
    </h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." required>
        <input type="button" value="Search">

    </form>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
            <li>List 3</li>
            <li>List 4</li>
            <li>List 5</li>
            <li>List 6</li> 
            <li>List 7</li> 
            <li>List 8</li>
            <li>List 9</li>
            <li>List 10</li>
            <li>List 11</li>
            <li>List 13</li>
            <li>List 13</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--<div style="width:500px; height:50px; background-color:grey; margin: auto; position: relative; bottom: 300px;"></div> -->

    <script>{
    var Dictionary = function(words) {...},
            words = Dictionary(words);

            document.getElementbyId("some_id").innerHTML= words; 
    }

    </script>

    <div id="ordid">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Display how and where?

Comment: Use `document.write()` or `.innerHTML`

Comment: @anas Thanks for the suggestion. Typing that out just put the plain text on the site though, how do I differentiate between text and code? I have to apologize for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: After reading your other comments, 1. Does your JS code lies inside a script tag? Maybe a good idea to post your html file, where everything should happen or link to a jsfiddle or similar

Comment: @pc-shooter I've loaded the javascript using    <script type="text/javascript" src="dic-dictionary.js"></script>. But I see your new answer, so we're talking about different things. Let's see if I can figure this out now, give me a moment.

Comment: And if your html code is long and messy (ahem, why?), try to clean out what isn't necessary for the question and provide a jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
document.write(var_name)
```

but it will display the output on a blank page.
An alternate can be to use `document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML` like this:

First create a `<div>` (for ex.) in your HTML:

```
<div id="some_id">

</div>
```

and then write this in your JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML=var_name;
```

Hope this clears up things.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nive00/vn5cfajd/)

**UPDATE:**

After seeing the HTML you added, you need to write `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementbyId`

and in place of `document.getElementById("some_id")`  you need to write the id of your `<div>` which I guess is`ordid`.

> ```
> <div id="ordid">
>
> </div>
> ```

(From your code)

A [*parial* Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nive00/vn5cfajd/1/) of your code.

You may see `10` at the top.

Comment: +1 except for the `.innerHTML()` method, which is a property, so `.innerHTML = `

Comment: The div is a go, but I still run into the problem where the document snippet doesn't seem to register as code. I just pasted the javascript code you provided into the javascript itself, but it's all black like normal text. I tried both on the inside and outside of the brackets in the javascript.

Comment: @Fendon You want to add CSS to the text?

Comment: No, I actually know some CSS myself, surprisingly enough, haha. My problem is still getting the data on the page. The javascript code with the "document" thing at the start hasn't worked in any of the answers I've gotten. I wonder if I've done something terribly wrong somewhere. I have loaded the relevant files into my html, so I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: I have added a demo. Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: My html is long and messy, should I edit the main post?

Comment: @Fendon Instead of 'document.getElementbyId' write `document.getElementById`

Comment: I just moved the div out of the body and it suddenly worked, I have no idea why. That tiny detail has caused so much confusion. Thanks for your help nivedita and @pc-shooter .

Comment: @Fendon could you accept Niveditas answer then. He had some work... ;-)